# Timeline drag is jumpy and unusuable

Tags: timeline

I'm unable to consistently drag the frame indicator on the timeline, or the dopesheet, or the vse, or anywhere the timeline is available. The cursor keeps jumping back to the previously selected frame. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm able to change frames with the 'current frame' field, but that's a pain. I have to restart blender.

Here is a link to a youtube video of the problem: https://youtu.be/h-fJN3gSkuY

Comment: i am not sure, but did you try set "no autosnap"? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIqs7.png